# How can I include Firebase and Snap Creative Kit as Gradle dependency

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, snapkit

I tried to use the Snap Creative Kit in my android project who is already using Firebase and I can not build due to this error :

```
Program type already present: com.google.protobuf.Any$1
```

Firebase Firestore uses `protobuf-lite` while Snap Creative Kit uses `protobuf-java`. I tried to exclude `protobuf-lite` from Firestore but the error persists. When I also exclude `com.google.firebase:protolite-well-known-types` from Firestore, the project builds but crashes.

**build.gradle (Project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://storage.googleapis.com/snap-kit-build/maven"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.snapchat.kit.sdk:creative:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-model-interpreter:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, the last version of Creative Kit resolved this issue. Just change

```
 implementation 'com.snapchat.kit.sdk:creative:1.0.2'
```

to

```
 implementation 'com.snapchat.kit.sdk:creative:1.1.3'
```